# X11 - Setting Cursor Position Not Working

Tags: linux, cursor, mouse, x11, windowing

I'm trying to set my X11 cursor position. I tried calling XWarpPointer with the window set to None, root (DefaultRootWindow(display)), to the previously created window (XCreateWindow). The function IS being called, the mouse slows down a bit, but it does not physically move. Why could this be?

```
void GameWindow::ResetCursor() {
    SetCursor(resX / 2, resY / 2);
}

void GameWindow::SetCursor(int x, int y) {
    // Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    XWarpPointer(display, None, root, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, y);
    XFlush(display);
}
```

EDIT: Here's the entire X11 Windowing file in case you can't find the reason here. https://gist.github.com/KarimIO/7db1f50778fda63a36c10242989baab6

Comment: Can't compile your source, there are no header files. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: My code is tens of thousands of lines long. Not sure exactly but pretty darn big.

Comment: You are supposed to reduce it down to a [mcve]. What about `xdotool mousemove_relative 50 50`, does it work for you?

Comment: I can try make an example soon but xdotool doesn't do anything.

Comment: So it looks like your X server prevents mouse warp from working. Are you using a VM perhaps?

Comment: So it's my laptop in particular? Is there any fix for that?

Comment: Also not using a VM. I'm dual booting Windows if that matters. I'm running an Ubuntu with Gnome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was relatively silly. I was using Gnome on Wayland, assuming it supported X11 as well. I assumed wrong.